# Create mysql table, parenthesis error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual ... for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 12

Tags: mysql

As a recent SQL learner, I've tried this piece of code for creating six tables through dozens of times, but cannot figure out what did the shell mean by saying that something is wrong near ")".

If there are obvious syntax errors, I could have fixed it.

Thank you for helping.

```
-- Table APPOINTMENT 

CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT (
  AppointmentID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DateAndTime VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  Venue VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PatientName VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  DoctorName VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PatientID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  DoctorID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  IsEmergency VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT "YES",
  IsVisited VARCHAR(3) DEFAULT "YES",
  PRIMARY KEY (AppointmentID),
);


-- Table PATIENT

CREATE TABLE PATIENT (
  PatientID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PatientName VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  Address VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  CurrentMedication VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  ChronicDisease VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  Allergies VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  MedicalHistory VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (PatientID),
);


-- Table DOCTOR

CREATE TABLE DOCTOR (
  DoctorID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  DoctorName VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (DoctorID),
);


-- Table BILL

CREATE TABLE BILL (
  AppointmentID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  DoctorID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PatientID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  DateAndTime VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  Diagnosis VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  Treatment VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  Fees INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  ServiceCharge INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  ClaimId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  InsuredDeduction INTEGER NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
  ReceiptNumber INTEGER NOT NULL,
  AmountPaid INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  TotalAmountDue INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (AppointmentID),
);


-- Table PAYMENT

CREATE TABLE PAYMENT (
  ReceiptNumber INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  AppointmentID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  AmountPaid INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PatientID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ReceiptNumber)
);


-- Table CLAIM

CREATE TABLE CLAIM (
  ClaimId INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  InsuranceCompanyName VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PatientID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ClaimId),
);


-- Foreign Keys 

ALTER TABLE APPOINTMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES PATIENT (PatientID);
ALTER TABLE APPOINTMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (DoctorID) REFERENCES DOCTOR (DoctorID);
ALTER TABLE PAYMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (AppointmentID) REFERENCES BILL (AppointmentID);
ALTER TABLE PAYMENT ADD FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES PATIENT (PatientID);
ALTER TABLE BILL ADD FOREIGN KEY (DoctorID) REFERENCES DOCTOR (DoctorID);
ALTER TABLE BILL ADD FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES PATIENT (PatientID);
ALTER TABLE BILL ADD FOREIGN KEY (ClaimId) REFERENCES CLAIM (ClaimId);
ALTER TABLE BILL ADD FOREIGN KEY (ReceiptNumber) REFERENCES PAYMENT (ReceiptNumber);
ALTER TABLE CLAIM ADD FOREIGN KEY (PatientID) REFERENCES PATIENT (PatientID);
```

Comment: Drop all the commas after PRIMARY KEY lines.

Comment: Thank you! What a shame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra comma in every create table statement. eg PRIMARY KEY (DoctorID) has a trailing comma. MySql expects another column declaration after that comma.

```
-- Table DOCTOR

CREATE TABLE DOCTOR (
 DoctorID VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
 DoctorName VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (DoctorID)
);
```